# sql server date issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a select statement that when run on the live production server, returns mm-dd-yyyy regardless of what I do.  this only happens though when selecting the date from an another aliased select.  Simplified (as my sql is quite long):-

```
select name,age,dob 
from tblone as tbltemp1
```

in this select, dob always mm/dd/yyyy not dd/mm/yyyy

```
select dob from tbltemp1
```

Hope that explanation makes sense and if anyone can help?

Comment: Help with what?, what it is that you actually want?

Comment: Add some actual details, such as the structure (in T-SQL) of the table in question.  You may want to clarify your actual question.

Comment: I think in your haste to simplify your long code, you've obliterated our ability to understand the problem. It appears you have an issue with the displayed format of a column. Is this merely a presentation issue or is the data itself getting converted? Also, in your opening paragraph, you indicate it's a `mm-dd-yyyy` format but later on you indicate it's `mm/dd/yyyy` not `dd/mm/yyyy` format as expected.

Comment: Apologies - did not mean to confuse.  The SQL is very long, so I have put it as a downloadable txt file here - the problem is line 54:-
http://www.woldsnewmedia.com/sql.txt

The SQL is used to populate the dataset in an SSRS file

Comment: There may be no need to post the entire query. What could be more useful is the type of the `dob` column, where you are executing the query and consuming the results, and possibly the locale settings of the system where you are executing the query as well.

Comment: tblPerson.DOB is just date - language of db is us_english

Comment: The SQL is used to populate an SSRS subreport.

Comment: Aliasing the table has NO EFFECT on the format of ANY of the data returned by the query.

Comment: Is that really the query or have you altered it? I see a RIGHT OUTER JOIN with no join criteria specified

Comment: My apologies.  I was rather too vague.  It turned out to be an issue with SSRS.  Sorry for wasting peoples time.

Answer (score 5):

Right so the value is probably a date and is preserved as a date when it gets to SSRS. SSRS is applying its own formatting to a date.

If you don't like that format, apply the correct specifier.

- http://thavash.wordpress.com/2007/10/02/date-formatting-in-reporting-services-list-of-format-codes/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975955/how-do-i-format-date-and-time-on-ssrs-report

etc

Answer (score -1):

The date format is based on the language setting

```
SELECT @@language
```

If you query the `sys.syslanguages` table you can see the date format for each language.  For example `us_english` is `mdy` and `british` is `dmy`.

The language can be changed using the `[SET LANGUAGE][1]` command.

```
SET LANGUAGE 'us_english'
```

Comment: If `dob` is a `date` or `datetime`, `SET LANGUAGE` will have no impact on how the column is displayed unless you do `CAST(dob AS varchar(…))`. If it's a `varchar` already, `SET LANGUAGE` will have no impact either. Therefore, `SET LANGUAGE` alone won't help here.